# Algorithm Behind Auto Contrast Feature in Photoshop

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, histogram, photoshop

I am struggling with pre-processing images in image recognition.

Up to now, I have tried:

- my custom solution like this in python

  ```py
  image_with_better_contrast = round(image/255,0) * 255
  ```
- [Histogram Equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) (better than previous)
- [CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization) (best of three)

But recently I compared **CLAHE** with the **Auto Contrast** feature of Photoshop on gray scale images - and results of **Auto Contrast** are impressive. I am excited to know about algorithm behind this feature.

**Note**: I know that Photoshop is proprietary software, and its code may be closed source. So any hint related to improving the CLAHE results, or any other algorithm, would be by me appreciated.

Comment: Please add the `Photoshop` tag.

Comment: I added, but then removed, as only 5 tags are alowed at maximum, wait I will add in place of machine-learning.

Answer (score 3):

While [CLAHE Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_histogram_equalization) is local by nature Photoshop's Auto Contrast is probably a global method.

I'd say it works on the Histogram of the image only by stretching the values in the image - [Image Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing)).
For instant, take RGB image and for each channel stretch its histogram as following (MATLAB Code):

```
for ii = 1:numChannels
    mOutputImage(:, :, ii) = (mOutputImage(:, :, ii) - max(max(mOutputImage(:, :, ii)))) ./ (max(max(mOutputImage(:, :, ii))) -  min(min(mOutputImage(:, :, ii))));
end
```

Another approach would be [Histogram Equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization).

Probably Photoshop is doing something more Advanced.
Maybe like doing it in the YUV Color Space, mixing the two or using more robust methods which looks on the percentiles of the histogram.

But this is the direction you should experiment with.

Comment: +1 , but waiting for more information, and YUV color space is for coloured images, I am only asking for gray scale images.

Comment: @RavinderPayal, So for GrayScale image you have single channel hence do what's written above only once.

Comment: OK, but please tell what's going under the hood in this line of code:-
` mOutputImage(:, :, ii) = (mOutputImage(:, :, ii) - max(max(mOutputImage(:, :, ii)))) ./ (max(max(mOutputImage(:, :, ii))) -  min(min(mOutputImage(:, :, ii))))`

Comment: You scale each value of the image according to its relative position on the range `[imageMinValue, imageMaxValue]'. Namely stretch the Image Histogram to have pure black and pure white.

Comment: So, basically it's an advanced version of this `image_with_better_contrast = round(image/255,0) * 255`. Thanks I will check if it produces desired results for images taken from hand-written noteboks. Thanks once again

Comment: It's not. Actually I don't understand what't the operation you used. It seem it would create black and white image or something,

Comment: Yeah it will create a pure black and white image, by making bright pixels more brighter and light pixels more lighter.